# Connection properties pops out when starting debug the MVC Solution in VS 2015

Tags: model-view-controller, properties, frameworks, connection, entity

When start the Debugging of solution using "F5" option, the connection properties pop out and ask to enter the credentials and connection properties for the database server in VS 2015 for MVC - Entity framework application.

Can some one help me to stop this pop out.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved when the Connection string in the web.config is edited in the project.

In the application project I had multiple connection string information and in which I too had an connection string which has local database information and that was in the first line, when I commented that database connection string information.

I had only on actual connection string information which point to the MS SQL server database, then issue is resolved and worked fine.